# How to handle newline characters in translated text?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I'm using Custom translator to translate Russian text into English. Some sentences contain `\n` character that means newline. And my goal is to translate the text like there are no newlines in it, but I want to preserve this `\n`.

Example
russian:

> очередь, к которой отнесен обработчик и в которой зарегистрированы
> данные, которые он будет обрабатывать.

English translation:

> queue to which the handler is assigned and in which the data that it
> will process is registered

This text can have `\n` in different places:

> очередь, к которой отнесен обработчик и в которой зарегистрированы
> данные, которые он будет`\n`обрабатывать.   очередь, к которой отнесен
> обработчик и в которой зарегистрированы данные`\n`
> которые он будет
> обрабатывать.   очередь, к которой отнесен обработчик и в
> которой`\n`зарегистрированы данные, которые он будет обрабатывать.

And all translations should match the first one, but preserving the '\n' position.

Is it possible? I've tried to replace `\n` with `<BR>` or with `&nbsp;` but the translation is different.

Comment: you can submit the different sentences as different items in the json array to the translate api. Then you can recombine your sentence after translation

Answer (score 1):

Wow! Found the solution!
Need to replace `\n` with `<b> </b>`

Answer (score 0):

I could not find an elegant way of doing it. But, found a workaround. You can replace the "\n" with some word or characters from a completely different script and the translator keep it as it is, without having any effect on the translation. After you get back the translated text you can replace your dummy word with "\n".

I translated

> очередь, к которой отнесен обработчик и в которой зарегистрированы
> данные, которые он будет मुखपृष्ठ обрабатывать. очередь, к которой
> отнесен обработчик и в которой зарегистрированы данные मुखपृष्ठ
> которые он будет обрабатывать. очередь, к которой отнесен обработчик и
> в которой मुखपृष्ठ зарегистрированы данные, которые он будет
> обрабатывать.

and it gave me

> the queue to which the handler is assigned and where the data that it
> will मुखपृष्ठ process is recorded. the queue to which the handler is
> assigned and in which the data मुखपृष्ठ which it will process is
> recorded. the queue to which the handler is assigned and in which the
> मुखपृष्ठ recorded the data that it will process.

Here I have used a "hindi" word "मुखपृष्ठ" but you can probably try with something like Japanese or something.

Just to repeat, this is just a workaround that I have found to be working at this moment, don't know if this is good enough for all kinds of use cases or if it continue to work in future.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes I think the possible way is to find some character that will not affect translation and that Custom translator will leave unchanged. But in your example translations are different:
`and where the data that it will process is recorded  

and in which the data which it will process is recorded  

and in which the recorded the data that it will process.`

Comment: This could affect the quality of translation and I would not recommend this approach